# Ionic 3 background image overlay (HTML & CSS) covering text

Tags: css, html, overlay, gradient, ionic3

I'm developing a mobile app in Ionic 3, and I cannot seem to solve this "simple" problem regarding my layout.

Here's the illustration. On the left is the result I'm getting, and on the right is the result I want to achieve. I cannot figure out why is the gradient covering my text (should be white).

[LINK TO IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlnR4.jpg)

And here's my code so far:

HTML

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-grid [style.padding]="0">
    <ion-row [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + img1 + ')'">
      <ion-col>
        <h1>HEADER</h1>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + img2 + ')'">
      <ion-col>
        <h1>HEADER</h1>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + img1 + ')'">
      <ion-col>
        <h1>HEADER</h1>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

and CSS:

```
page-home {
    scroll-content {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    ion-grid {
        height: 100%;
    }
    ion-row {
        flex: 1;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    ion-col {
        z-index: 0;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0.8;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    }
    h1 {
        color: white;
    }
}
```

I've tried different combinations with a row-column system, also adding two divs inside the column and applying the image and effects to them, tried with z-index, but nothing works. 
Also, the rows will probably be generated with `*ngFor` and populated with fetched content, so that's why there's a variable for bg image.

Comment: sorry but I don't see the difference between left and right...  Is it just that you want the text white?

Comment: On the left (the result I'm currently getting), the text is behind the gradient layer, and the text is grey, not white as it should be. So, I want the text to be on top of both the image and the gradient overlay (overlay should be applied to an image only). Hope it's more clear now. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I spotted the issue. It's in your ion-col div:

```
 ion-col {
        z-index: 0;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0.8; /* Here's the issue */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    }
```

The gradient overlay is not covering the text, it's just that you've set the div's opacity to .8 which will affect all it's child elements.

Here's an alternative solution:

```
ion-col {
        z-index: 0;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 100%); /* I added the 0.8 opacity here, to the last rgba which won't affect the child element */
    }
```

Comment: Hey buddy, thanks a lot! You're right, I missed that one. Cheers!